# Not to start the bibliography in a new page

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking

I'm using `thebibliography` in order to do the bibliography of my text.

Here is what I have written:

```
      \begin{thebibliography}{99}
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliografia}
      \bibitem{uno}...
      \end{thebibliography}
```

I have this problem: my bibliography starts in a new page, while I would like to have it just at the end of the text. How can I do this?
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Please include a MWE (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Comment: Try to add `\clearpage` before `\begin{thebibliography}{99}`.

Answer (score 3):

Since no MWE is given, this is a quick guess: The responsible command for the  newpage is the `\chapter*{\bibname}` within the definition of `thebibliography` environment (most likely the `book` or `report` class is used). This command issues a `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` depending on class options.

I have patched the `thebibliography` command by relaxing `\clearpage` just before `\chapter*` is used.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\par\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*}{\typeout{success}}{\typeout{failure}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}%
\blindtext[10]
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}
\bibitem{uno}...
\end{thebibliography} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If a section is written to the contents, wouldn't it be more reasonable to use a section instead of a chapter? Something like the KOMA-option `bibliography=leveldown`.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes, but I kept that from the OP.